# Run shell script from within an R script on a windows machine

Tags: r, shell, cygwin, rscript

I have a R-script within which i call a shell script using system command and use the paste command to pass arguments to the shell script ( on unix machine) and i now would like execute the same R-script on a windows machine and am struggling to get it working

Here are the steps i followed
R code

```
source('C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\R\\R-3.5.2\\ms\\ms\\MS_Config.R')


if(is.null(git_version) | git_version == "" | length(git_version) == 0){
    print('ERROR: EXECUTION STOPPED !!!')
    print('PLEASE SPECIFY GITHUB TAG_ID')
    stop()
}


print("test4444")
print(enable_data_pull)
print (getwd())


system(paste('C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\R\\R- 3.5.2\\ms\\ms\\MS_ALLM_Parallel_Runner.sh -c ', num_cores, 
         '-s ', snapshot_dt, 
         '-p ' , local_storage_path, 
         '-t ', tag, 
         '-g ', git_version,
         '-y ', enable_data_pull

))


print ("after shell script execution")
```

I tried the following, but did not succeed

Installed cygwin and called the rscript from the cygwin terminal(PATH variable is updated to include R and its binaries)

1. rscript "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\R\R-3.5.2\ms\ms\MS_Model_Kickoff.R"

Below is the error message that i see after the r-script attempts to run the shell script

> 'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\xxxx\DOCUME~1\R\R-35~1.2\ms\ms\CONRM_~1.SH -c  25 -s  201811 -p  C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Test -t  Analytical -g  verModelRefit2.2.2 -y  N'

what does the above error mean and how do i fix this and execute the shell script within from the R-script on windows machine?r

Comment: Maybe I'm completly wrong, but I think you cannot run a shell script (*.sh) on a Windows-machine, can you?

Comment: It's not possible using windows command line, but it is possible through cygwin terminal. am kind of stuck with what i have to achieve, need to my R script to execute the shell script which is being called from within the r script

Comment: The error message that you display does not agree with the code that you show us. They refer to different programs.

Comment: I call the rscript "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\R\R-3.5.2\ms\ms\MS_Model_Kickoff.R" which in turn takes some input parametes from another rscript(source('C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\R\\R-3.5.2\\ms\\ms\\MS_Config.R')) and then calls the shell script as mentioned above and the error message does belong to the same program meaning it refers to rscript "MS_Model_Kickoff.R"